# Are there any airlines which offer two complimentary checked bags to all passengers on transatlantic flights?

Tags: luggage, airlines, regulations

The vast majority of airlines operating flights between North America and Europe have now restricted standard economy passengers to checking just one complimentary piece of luggage. Some airlines are not even allowing *any* free baggage on some ticket types, meaning it's no longer a universal benefit that comes with purchasing any type of ticket. This is the opposite for trans*pacific* flights, on which checking two bags is a universal benefit on nearly every airline (except budget ones).

Are there any airlines that offer two complimentary checked bags as a universal benefit to all passengers traveling **transatlantic** (as in their itinerary is transatlantic), no matter what cabin class they're traveling in, their elite status, or (as a bonus) the type of ticket they've purchased?

As an example, Air India used to do so on their fifth-freedom flights between Newark and London Heathrow, but they've since discontinued this route in favor of nonstops to India, and even if it were still operating, they've restricted passengers traveling via Newark to just one free bag.

Comment: I thought there was a special case for international flights from Brasil which included 2 bags free of charge in all cases by law, but it seems to have been discontinued back in 2017...

Comment: Plenty of airlines offer two free bags for certain kinds of economy tickets. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I agree with Willeke, it will be outdated sooner or later. Forcing all passengers to pay for two bags will be a disadvantage for the airline since passengers with less than two bags will choose cheaper options.

Comment: @jcaron It's not discontinued. They just reduced the required weight limit from 32 to 23 kilograms.

Comment: @Willeke For U.S. domestic flights, we have an airline Southwest Airlines that offers two free bags to all passengers universally, even in the face of *all* other competitors offering zero free bags and increasing fees. They continue with this policy because they feel that giving people the option to check more bags should the need arise later will give them a competitive advantage. People still buy tickets for them even when they have hand luggage only and even when their fare costs slightly more, to make themselves "insured".

Comment: @Anders See the above comment. It's not always a disadvantage. Also, with the current system, those with two bags will have to pay more overall than back when two bags were included (factoring in inflation and oil prices). And back when Air India operated the EWR-LHR route, they charged almost the same price as United and BA.

Answer (score 5):

Singapore Airlines flies between New York (JFK) and Frankfurt, and their [current baggage policy](https://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/us/travel-info/baggage/checked-baggage/) is at least two bags (up to 23kg each) for economy class flights to or from the US.

Answer (score 3):

There might be some, but you should always look at the overall price for the flight and the luggage together.

There is no advantage of booking an 800 $ flight to get two free pieces of luggage, when you can book a 400 $ flight, and add 2 x 60 $ for luggage to it.

Answer (score 2):

Air Serbia allows this on its direct flight between Belgrade and JFK.

https://www.airserbia.com/en/information/baggage/checked-baggage/checked-baggage-weight

[image]